# como faço para ajustar o img de um icone

Tags: html, css

estou querendo ajustar o img de um icone mas não estou conseguindo, já tentei colocar margin de 10 px e nada

CÓDIGO DO HTML:

clique aqui: (img do icone do twitter) para acessar o meu twitter

CÓDIGO:CSS

img.twitter{

```
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

caso width e height, não funcionar tente pelo: `position: absolute;`

um ícone trabalha como um texto, logo você pode usar um font-size para tamanho do ícone: `font-size: 40px;`

obs: pode utilizar como flex, bem melhor;
`display: flex;`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).